# Ruby On Rails: example of file_field on form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I came across file uploading problem in Rails. I found `file_field :file` helper, that can be used with `form_for(@some_model)`. However, I cannot find any usage for this case, as those tags are used to create/edit some model, by mass assigning. There is, AFAIK, no possibility to treat fileupload as typical field ( See [File upload won't work in Ruby on Rails 3 using Multipart Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678962/file-upload-wont-work-in-ruby-on-rails-3-using-multipart-form) ). In such a case, manual operation on uploaded file is required. So, why would someone even want to puts a fileupload as a part of model editing?

photo.rb

```
   class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
       attr_accessible :name, :filename,
   end
```

photo_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@photo, :multipart => true) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %> 
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.file_field :file %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

photos_controller.rb

```
def create
    @photo = Photo.new(params[:photo])
```

line above fails, because theres no :file attribute. It must be handled before and manually removed from `:params`. Once more - is there any real usage for such tags?

Comment: Hey, if you have got any idea of how to achieve file uploading using form_for while having other fields and labels, please share it here. Even I'm trying to make this work.

Comment: And it would be nice if there is no need to use any gem.

Comment: What happens if you try `attr_accesible :name, :file` and in your view `<%= f.file_field :filename %>`?

Answer (score 6):

I will will you an example how I am using it I think it explains itself good enough, I hope this helps

```
 <%= form_for @item do |f|%>
    <%= f.file_field :photo, accept: 'image/png,image/jpeg'%>
 <% end %>
```

Let me know if you have any doubts

Answer (score 5):

I remember that I used this to upload a xml file in Rails

view:

```
<%= form_tag({action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
   <%= file_field_tag 'xml_file' %>
   <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def upload
    file_data = params[:xml_file]
end
```

It is using form_tag but it would not be hard to add other info into that form also.