# Rails helper file_field won't accept one parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use

```
<%= file_field :upload %>
```

rails raises an error, saying I should supply 2..3 parameters to `file_field`. If I use

```
<%= file_field :upload, :file %>
```

things go fine. But I do not want the file param to be `params[:upload][:file]`, I want it to be `params[:upload]`.

Why I can't supply just one parameter to `file_field` and get the desired param?

Also what is the solution to this problem 
[[Ruby On Rails: example of file_field on form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001034/ruby-on-rails-example-of-file-field-on-form-for])? There isn't a proper solution posted there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve what you want is to replace `file_field` with `file_field_tag`:

```
<%= file_field_tag :upload %>
```

You can provide only one parametr and it will turns to:

```
<input type="file" name="upload" id="upload">
```

And you will be able to access it: `params[:upload]`